# The FOV for my 3D engine built upon C++ and SFML doesn't get updated, resulting in weird deformation

Tags: c++, 3d, sfml

I realize this is a niche and rather uncommon issue, but I'm creating a 3D engine within SFML where, at the moment, I've only gotten a wireframe cube to be drawn with rotation. The issue arises, however, when I apply FOV, resulting in the elongation of the cube.

[image: Elongated cube]

Here is my code (sorry, it's messy):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>

void rotate(float& rotx, float& roty, float& rotz, 
    float &n1x, float &n1y, float &n1z, float &n2x, float &n2y, float &n2z, 
    float &n3x, float &n3y, float &n3z, float &n4x, float &n4y, float &n4z,
    float &nd1x, float &nd1y, float &nd1z, float &nd2x, float &nd2y, float &nd2z, 
    float &nd3x, float &nd3y, float &nd3z, float &nd4x, float &nd4y, float &nd4z);

int main()
{
    int srx = 1920;
    int sry = 1080;

    sf::ContextSettings settings;
    settings.antialiasingLevel = 8;
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(srx, sry), "Cube is not look good", sf::Style::Default, settings);

    window.setFramerateLimit(100);
    sf::View view(sf::Vector2f(0.0f, 0.0f), sf::Vector2f(srx, sry));
    sf::Vector2f scr_res(srx, sry);
    sf::Vector2f srd2(scr_res.x / 2, scr_res.y / 2);

    sf::Vector3f origin(0, 0, 0);

    float cetz = 0.00000000001;
    float factor = 150;
    float x_n1 = origin.x - factor;
    float x_n2 = origin.x + factor;
    float x_n3 = origin.x + factor;
    float x_n4 = origin.x - factor;
    float x_n1_d = origin.x - factor;
    float x_n2_d = origin.x + factor;
    float x_n3_d = origin.x + factor;
    float x_n4_d = origin.x - factor;
    float y_n1 = origin.y - factor;
    float y_n2 = origin.y - factor;
    float y_n3 = origin.y + factor;
    float y_n4 = origin.y + factor;
    float y_n1_d = origin.y - factor;
    float y_n2_d = origin.y - factor;
    float y_n3_d = origin.y + factor;
    float y_n4_d = origin.y + factor;
    float arb_z1 = origin.z - factor;
    float arb_z2 = origin.z - factor;
    float arb_z3 = origin.z - factor;
    float arb_z4 = origin.z - factor;
    float arb_z_d1 = origin.z + factor;
    float arb_z_d2 = origin.z + factor;
    float arb_z_d3 = origin.z + factor;
    float arb_z_d4 = origin.z + factor;

    sf::Vector3f n1(x_n1, y_n1, arb_z1);
    sf::Vector3f n2(x_n2, y_n2, arb_z2);
    sf::Vector3f n3(x_n3, y_n3, arb_z3);
    sf::Vector3f n4(x_n4, y_n4, arb_z4);

    /*
      _______
     /______/|
    |      | | <-- nd's
    |      | |
    |______|/
        ^
        |
       n's
    */

    sf::Vector3f n1d(x_n1_d, y_n1_d, arb_z_d1);
    sf::Vector3f n2d(x_n2_d, y_n2_d, arb_z_d2);
    sf::Vector3f n3d(x_n3_d, y_n3_d, arb_z_d3);
    sf::Vector3f n4d(x_n4_d, y_n4_d, arb_z_d4);

    float fov = 90;

    sf::Vector3f rot(0,0,0);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        
        //Rotates the cube on the Y axis
        rot.y += 0.01;

         //z0 means distance from screen; if the fov = 180, z0 = 0 which makes the cube srink to a dot
        float z0 = (scr_res.x / 2.0) / (tan((fov / 2.0) * 3.14159265 / 180.0));

        //Applies FOV
        n1.x = x_n1 * (z0 / (z0 + arb_z1));
        n1.y = y_n1 * (z0 / (z0 + arb_z1));
        n2.x = x_n2 * (z0 / (z0 + arb_z2));
        n2.y = y_n2 * (z0 / (z0 + arb_z2));
        n3.x = x_n3 * (z0 / (z0 + arb_z3));
        n3.y = y_n3 * (z0 / (z0 + arb_z3));
        n4.x = x_n4 * (z0 / (z0 + arb_z4));
        n4.y = y_n4 * (z0 / (z0 + arb_z4));
        n1d.x = x_n1_d * (z0 / (z0 + arb_z_d1));
        n1d.y = y_n1_d * (z0 / (z0 + arb_z_d1));
        n2d.x = x_n2_d * (z0 / (z0 + arb_z_d2));
        n2d.y = y_n2_d * (z0 / (z0 + arb_z_d2));
        n3d.x = x_n3_d * (z0 / (z0 + arb_z_d3));
        n3d.y = y_n3_d * (z0 / (z0 + arb_z_d3));
        n4d.x = x_n4_d * (z0 / (z0 + arb_z_d4));
        n4d.y = y_n4_d * (z0 / (z0 + arb_z_d4));
        n1.z = arb_z1;
        n2.z = arb_z2;
        n3.z = arb_z3;
        n4.z = arb_z4;
        n1d.z = arb_z_d1;
        n2d.z = arb_z_d2;
        n3d.z = arb_z_d3;
        n4d.z = arb_z_d4;

        //Applies Rotation
    rotate(rot.x, rot.y, rot.z, 
        n1.x, n1.y, n1.z, n2.x, n2.y, n2.z, 
        n3.x, n3.y, n3.z, n4.x, n4.y, n4.z,
        n1d.x, n1d.y, n1d.z, n2d.x, n2d.y, n2d.z, 
        n3d.x, n3d.y, n3d.z, n4d.x, n4d.y, n4d.z);

        //Drawing the front face (or 4 lines) which goes clockwise (12, 3, 6, 9) uses the subscript f 
        sf::Vertex line12f[] =
        {
         sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(n1.x, n1.y)),
        sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(n2.x, n2.y))
        };
        sf::Vertex line3f[] =
        {
        sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(n2.x, n2.y)),
        sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(n3.x, n3.y))
        };
        sf::Vertex line6f[] =
        {
        sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(n3.x, n3.y)),
        sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(n4.x, n4.y))
        };
        sf::Vertex line9f[] =
        {
        sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(n4.x, n4.y)),
        sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(n1.x, n1.y))
        };
        //Drawing the back face (or 4 lines) which goes clockwise (12, 3, 6, 9) uses the subscript b
        sf::Vertex line12b[] =
        {
        sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(n1d.x, n1d.y)),
        sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(n2d.x, n2d.y))
        };
        sf::Vertex line3b[] =
        {
        sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(n2d.x, n2d.y)),
        sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(n3d.x, n3d.y))
        };
        sf::Vertex line6b[] =
        {
        sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(n3d.x, n3d.y)),
        sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(n4d.x, n4d.y))
        };
        sf::Vertex line9b[] =
        {
        sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(n4d.x, n4d.y)),
        sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(n1d.x, n1d.y))
        };
        //Drawing the lines connecting the back and front face (4 lines) which goes clockwise and uses the subscript r
        sf::Vertex line12r[] =
        {
        sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(n1.x, n1.y)),
        sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(n1d.x, n1d.y))
        };
        sf::Vertex line3r[] =
        {
        sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(n2.x, n2.y)),
        sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(n2d.x, n2d.y))
        };
        sf::Vertex line6r[] =
        {
        sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(n3.x, n3.y)),
        sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(n3d.x, n3d.y))
        };
        sf::Vertex line9r[] =
        {
        sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(n4.x, n4.y)),
        sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(n4d.x, n4d.y))
        };


        sf::Event event;

        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            switch (event.type)
            {
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                window.close();

                break;

            }
        }

        window.clear();
        window.setView(view);
        window.draw(line12f, 2, sf::Lines);
        window.draw(line3f, 2, sf::Lines);
        window.draw(line6f, 2, sf::Lines);
        window.draw(line9f, 2, sf::Lines);

        window.draw(line12b, 2, sf::Lines);
        window.draw(line3b, 2, sf::Lines);
        window.draw(line6b, 2, sf::Lines);
        window.draw(line9b, 2, sf::Lines);

        window.draw(line12r, 2, sf::Lines);
        window.draw(line3r, 2, sf::Lines);
        window.draw(line6r, 2, sf::Lines);
        window.draw(line9r, 2, sf::Lines);

        window.display();
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void rotate(float &rotx, float &roty, float &rotz, 
    float &n1x, float &n1y, float &n1z, float &n2x, float &n2y, float &n2z, 
    float &n3x, float &n3y, float &n3z, float &n4x, float &n4y, float &n4z,
    float &nd1x, float &nd1y, float &nd1z, float &nd2x, float &nd2y, float &nd2z, 
    float &nd3x, float &nd3y, float &nd3z, float &nd4x, float &nd4y, float &nd4z) {

    n1x = n1x * (cos(rotz) * cos(roty)) +
        n1y * (cos(rotz) * sin(roty) * sin(rotx) - sin(rotz) * cos(rotx)) +
        n1z * (cos(rotz) * sin(roty) * cos(rotx) + sin(rotz) * sin(rotx));
    n1y = n1x * (sin(rotz) * cos(roty)) +
        n1y * (sin(rotz) * sin(roty) * sin(rotx) + cos(rotz) * cos(rotx)) +
        n1z * (sin(rotz) * sin(roty) * cos(rotx) - cos(rotz) * sin(rotx));
    n1z = n1x * (-sin(roty)) +
        n1y * (cos(roty) * sin(rotx)) +
        n1z * (cos(roty) * cos(rotx));

    n2x = n2x * (cos(rotz) * cos(roty)) +
        n2y * (cos(rotz) * sin(roty) * sin(rotx) - sin(rotz) * cos(rotx)) +
        n2z * (cos(rotz) * sin(roty) * cos(rotx) + sin(rotz) * sin(rotx));
    n2y = n2x * (sin(rotz) * cos(roty)) +
        n2y * (sin(rotz) * sin(roty) * sin(rotx) + cos(rotz) * cos(rotx)) +
        n2z * (sin(rotz) * sin(roty) * cos(rotx) - cos(rotz) * sin(rotx));
    n2z = n2x * (-sin(roty)) +
        n2y * (cos(roty) * sin(rotx)) +
        n2z * (cos(roty) * cos(rotx));

    n3x = n3x * (cos(rotz) * cos(roty)) +
        n3y * (cos(rotz) * sin(roty) * sin(rotx) - sin(rotz) * cos(rotx)) +
        n3z * (cos(rotz) * sin(roty) * cos(rotx) + sin(rotz) * sin(rotx));
    n3y = n3x * (sin(rotz) * cos(roty)) +
        n3y * (sin(rotz) * sin(roty) * sin(rotx) + cos(rotz) * cos(rotx)) +
        n3z * (sin(rotz) * sin(roty) * cos(rotx) - cos(rotz) * sin(rotx));
    n3z = n3x * (-sin(roty)) +
        n3y * (cos(roty) * sin(rotx)) +
        n3z * (cos(roty) * cos(rotx));

    n4x = n4x * (cos(rotz) * cos(roty)) +
        n4y * (cos(rotz) * sin(roty) * sin(rotx) - sin(rotz) * cos(rotx)) +
        n4z * (cos(rotz) * sin(roty) * cos(rotx) + sin(rotz) * sin(rotx));
    n4y = n4x * (sin(rotz) * cos(roty)) +
        n4y * (sin(rotz) * sin(roty) * sin(rotx) + cos(rotz) * cos(rotx)) +
        n4z * (sin(rotz) * sin(roty) * cos(rotx) - cos(rotz) * sin(rotx));
    n4z = n4x * (-sin(roty)) +
        n4y * (cos(roty) * sin(rotx)) +
        n4z * (cos(roty) * cos(rotx));

    nd1x = nd1x * (cos(rotz) * cos(roty)) +
        nd1y * (cos(rotz) * sin(roty) * sin(rotx) - sin(rotz) * cos(rotx)) +
        nd1z * (cos(rotz) * sin(roty) * cos(rotx) + sin(rotz) * sin(rotx));
    nd1y = nd1x * (sin(rotz) * cos(roty)) +
        nd1y * (sin(rotz) * sin(roty) * sin(rotx) + cos(rotz) * cos(rotx)) +
        nd1z * (sin(rotz) * sin(roty) * cos(rotx) - cos(rotz) * sin(rotx));
    nd1z = nd1x * (-sin(roty)) +
        nd1y * (cos(roty) * sin(rotx)) +
        nd1z * (cos(roty) * cos(rotx));

    nd2x = nd2x * (cos(rotz) * cos(roty)) +
        nd2y * (cos(rotz) * sin(roty) * sin(rotx) - sin(rotz) * cos(rotx)) +
        nd2z * (cos(rotz) * sin(roty) * cos(rotx) + sin(rotz) * sin(rotx));
    nd2y = nd2x * (sin(rotz) * cos(roty)) +
        nd2y * (sin(rotz) * sin(roty) * sin(rotx) + cos(rotz) * cos(rotx)) +
        nd2z * (sin(rotz) * sin(roty) * cos(rotx) - cos(rotz) * sin(rotx));
    nd2z = nd2x * (-sin(roty)) +
        nd2y * (cos(roty) * sin(rotx)) +
        nd2z * (cos(roty) * cos(rotx));

    nd3x = nd3x * (cos(rotz) * cos(roty)) +
        nd3y * (cos(rotz) * sin(roty) * sin(rotx) - sin(rotz) * cos(rotx)) +
        nd3z * (cos(rotz) * sin(roty) * cos(rotx) + sin(rotz) * sin(rotx));
    nd3y = nd3x * (sin(rotz) * cos(roty)) +
        nd3y * (sin(rotz) * sin(roty) * sin(rotx) + cos(rotz) * cos(rotx)) +
        nd3z * (sin(rotz) * sin(roty) * cos(rotx) - cos(rotz) * sin(rotx));
    nd3z = nd3x * (-sin(roty)) +
        nd3y * (cos(roty) * sin(rotx)) +
        nd3z * (cos(roty) * cos(rotx));

    nd4x = nd4x * (cos(rotz) * cos(roty)) +
        nd4y * (cos(rotz) * sin(roty) * sin(rotx) - sin(rotz) * cos(rotx)) +
        nd4z * (cos(rotz) * sin(roty) * cos(rotx) + sin(rotz) * sin(rotx));
    nd4y = nd4x * (sin(rotz) * cos(roty)) +
        nd4y * (sin(rotz) * sin(roty) * sin(rotx) + cos(rotz) * cos(rotx)) +
        nd4z * (sin(rotz) * sin(roty) * cos(rotx) - cos(rotz) * sin(rotx));
    nd4z = nd4x * (-sin(roty)) +
        nd4y * (cos(roty) * sin(rotx)) +
        nd4z * (cos(roty) * cos(rotx));

    return;
}
```

I suppose the summary of my issue is that the FOV applied to the points of the cube doesn't get updated, resulting in the weird deformation. If anybody has an idea on how to fix this, it would be much appritiated. Thanks!

Comment: With a couple of extra functions and some arrays, your code would be both short and readable.

Comment: @paddy, I know, I just felt like getting the FOV working before I did a big code clean-up.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).